# Сохранение DOM-объектов

Tags: jquery, dom

Такое дело: на странице есть gif-изображение, которое должно показываться во время  ajax-загрузки контента. Изображение прописано в html-коде

```
<img src="img.gif" id="img" style="display: none">
```

Перед загрузкой данных я его показываю в диве:

```
$('#myDiv').append($('#img').show());
```

После загрузки контента в этот же див, я так понял,  изображение удаляется из DOM. И я не могу его повторно использовать. Я пробовал выводить не само изображение, а его клон, но наверное есть более лаконичное решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если необходимо многоразовое использование гифки, то да, все верно, нужно ее копировать:

```
$('#myDiv').append($('#img').clone().show());
```

Только я бы копировал по класу, чтобы в дом-дереве не было 2х элементов с одинаковым id.

Возможно создать и хранить обьект в коде, а не в ХТМЛ, но перед вставкой его все равно нужно копировать, либо сохранять перед вставкой нового контента:

```
var loader = $('<img/>').attr({'src':'img.gif'}).hide();
$('#myDiv').append(loader.clone().show());
```

Comment: Да с дивом я протормозил, класс нужно использовать. Спасибо, что развенчали мои сомнения.

Comment: @Vitalii Vaslianok, кстати, если в вашем примере сделать переменную loader глобальной (window.loader), то копировать ее не нужно будет, ссылка на объект не уничтожается в данном случае.